# Probability that no person can solve the problem

Tags: probability

> Three persons work independently on a problem. If the respective
>   probabilities that they will solve it are $\dfrac 13 , \dfrac 14,
>  \dfrac 15$, then find the probability that none can solve it.

I think it should be:

$1 - \text{Probability that all solve it correctly}$

$ = 1- \dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{1}{5}$

$= \dfrac{59}{60}$

But author does it this way:

$(1- \frac 13)(1- \frac 14)(1- \frac 15) = \frac 2 5$

I am not able to understand/ figure out why I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression
$$
1 - \text{Probability that all solve it correctly}
$$
represents the probability that at least one of them gets it wrong, because that's the negation of "everyone gets it right". All three of them geting it wrong is not the same thing.

The probabilities for each of them to get it wrong are $1-\frac13$, $1-\frac14$ and $1-\frac15$ respectively. The probability that all three get it wrong is therefore the product of these three, which is what your teacher did.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that exactly one of them solves it.

The complement of "none can solve it" is not "everyone can solve it", it is "someone can solve it".